# Postgres inner join or complicated selects?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Let's say I have the example below in the picture, with the intended result below the tables

[image: example]

So far, I am able to get the rental count with

```
SELECT inventory.film_id,
SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rental WHERE rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id)) AS rentals,
(SELECT title FROM film WHERE film.film_id = inventory.film_id) AS title
FROM inventory
GROUP BY inventory.film_id
ORDER BY inventory.film_id
```

Result

```
film_id   rentals    title
1         23         Academy Dinosaur
2          7         Ace Goldfinger
.         ..         ................
```

I just cannot seem to figure out how to get lets say, category.name from linking film_id to film_category then to category. I have tried adding this code

```
INNER JOIN film_category ON inventory.film_id = film_category.film_id
```

but it just returns the same result, it doesn't join it. This wouldn't grab category.name anyways like I am needing.

Any help in understanding what the logic is behind this example would be awesome. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write simple query using JOIN

```
SELECT inventory.film_id, film.title, COUNT(*) AS rentals
FROM inventory
JOIN rental ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
JOIN film ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id
GROUP BY inventory.film_id, film.title
ORDER BY inventory.film_id;
```

[PostgreSQL live example](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/39d99143e786337bb4bac68dd054b002/)

If you need to get film categories use next version:

```
SELECT 
    inventory.film_id, 
    film.title, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT rental_id) AS rentals, 
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT category.title)
FROM inventory
JOIN rental ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
JOIN film ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id
JOIN film_category ON film_category.film_id = inventory.film_id
JOIN category ON film_category.category_id = category.category_id
GROUP BY inventory.film_id, film.title
ORDER BY inventory.film_id;
```

[fiddle here](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/810cda79ff176335dcd33d6cc7b3a81e/)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure out what was going on with that code and got the category name showing now.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful here. A film can have many rentals and belong to many categories. So you want to join the number of rentals and the list of categories. This means, you should first aggregate your data and then join:

```
select f.film_id, f.title, c.categories, r.number_of_rentals
from film f
left join
(
  select fc.film_id, string_agg(c.name, ', ' order by c.name) as categories
  from film_category fc
  join category c on c.category_id = fc.category_id
  group by fc.film_id
) c on c.film_id = f.film_id
left join
(
  select i.film_id, count(*) as number_of_rentals
  from rental r
  join inventory in on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
  group by i.film_id
) r on r.film_id = f.film_id
order by f.film_id;
```

Comment: There are some typos that I fixed but realized a lot of those tables don't include the fields listed. Film doesn't have name, Category doesn't have categories, etc. This is a little hard to follow, the other answer got me where I needed to be simpler, but I will be looking at this further if I need some more complex querying. Thanks!

Comment: `categories` is an alias name. It is not a column in any of the tables. Yes, I was mistaken with `f.name` instead of `f.title`, but was this actually that hard to spot? Slava Rozhnev's new answer works, but is muddling through. It is also using a rental_id that doesn't exist according to your images. You can use it, but be aware that it builds an unnecessarily big intermediate result, so the query can become comparably slow when the tables' data gets bigger.

Comment: ah I didn't see the categories alias. And no it wasn't hard to spot, I corrected it but got more errors, idr what now. Slava edited his answer, I haven't looked at the second part. I took the first part and made some modifications, mainly just adding a join for film_category and category. My main purpose was to get an understanding of how this worked as opposed to having someone write the code for me. If you're suggesting your code will be more efficient then I will take another look at it. also, the tables don't associate more than 1 category to each film, each film just associates with 1

Comment: Okay, your data model suggests that there can be any number of categories for a film. Hence the bridge table `film_category` as opposed to having one `category_id` in the `film` table. If you see it guaranteed that there can only be one category per film (in which case I'd suggest to change the data model accordingly), my query has no advantage, because the categories won't have to be aggregated. It's only when dealing with multiple aggregates that it is advisable to first aggregate and then join to avoid side effects and longer runtime.

Comment: Well the main issue I was having was aggregating the rentals because there are more than 1 of each inventory id, and more than 1 inventory id for each film. I believe the way I was doing it was what was causing the joins to not work. I think this solution might still be applicable so I'll look over it. I need to understand more about SQL, specifically postgres, anyways, so thanks again.